I cant get my vba to make a directory folder on my desktop. I am pulling data from multiple sheets. Everything debugs with no issues so confused now
Sub WO_SaveUpdate()
Dim WORow As Long, WOCol As Long
Dim AssignedTo As String, SharedFolder As String, FileName As String, FilePath As String
With Sheet1
 If .Range("D4").Value = Empty Or .Range("H4").Value = Empty Or .Range("D10").Value = Empty Or .Range("C15").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please Complete Yellow Boxes"
    Exit Sub
 End If
 End With


With Sheet3
If .Range("C4").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please add in a shared folder location"
    Exit Sub
End If
End With

With Sheet2
If Worksheets("WO Data").Range("B11").Value = True Then 'new WOrk order
    WORow = .Range("C99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1  'First Avail. Row
Else ' Existing Work Order
End If
End With


With Sheet1
 For WOCol = 3 To 11
   Sheet2.Cells(WORow, WOCol).Value = .Range(.Cells(30, WOCol).Value).Value 'Place values in WO Row
    Sheet4.Range(.Cells(29, WOCol).Value).Value = .Range(.Cells(30, WOCol).Value).Value 'Place Values in WO Template
 Next WOCol
 Sheet2.Range("B11").Value = False 'Set new WO to false
Sheet2.Range("B12").Value = WORow


'Create/Update Work Order in Shared folder if status is Open
If .Range("D8").Value = "Open" Then
    AssignedTo = .Range("H4").Value 'Assigned To
    SharedFolder = Sheet3.Range("C4").Value 'Shared Folder location
    FileName = "Work Order_" & .Range("D6").Value 'File Name Work Order & #
    If Dir(SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir (SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo) 'Create Folder if it does not exist
    MsgBox ("test")
    End If
    FilePath = SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo & "\" & FileName & ".xlsx"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill (FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheet4.Range("A1:B26").Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FilePath
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Sheet2.Range("G" & WORow).Value = Now 'Update Assigned On to Current date & Time
    End If
    
End With
    
End Sub


Does the location in SharedFolder exist? VBA cannot create a folder if it has to create multiple folders in succession, Also, what error do you get, and what line is highlighted?

Yes the location exist ! There is no error that is what is confusing. The location is going directly to my desktop !

Can you change the IF for checking the path to multiple rows using end if, and put a message box in there that the folder does not exist? I have a feeling somehow it thinks the folder exists.

Can you give me example please

Is there a way to add file here ?

Change this line: If Dir(SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir (SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo) 'Create Folder if it does not exist to If Dir(SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo, vbDirectory) = "" Then <enter>MkDir (SharedFolder & "\" & AssignedTo) 'Create Folder if it does not exist <enter>msgbox ("test") <enter>End If and make sure you replace <enter> with actual enters.

If .Range("D8").Value = "Open" Then
AssignedTo = .Range("H4").Value 'Assigned To
SharedFolder = Sheet3.Range("C4").Value 'Shared Folder location
FileName = "Work Order_" & .Range("D6").Value 'File Name Work Order & #
If Dir(SharedFolder & "" & AssignedTo, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir (SharedFolder & "" & AssignedTo) 'Create Folder if it does not exist
MsgBox ("test")
End If
Still same results

i wonder if its because its trying to pull data from multiple sheets?

Can you update the code in your question so it references what you have currently?

Yes I will currently at work give me a few

I have updated the code as you wanted. Debug still finds no errors and when i run the script ,it still does not make a folder on desktop.

Does it give you the test popup? If not, then that means that the code thinks the directory already exists, so you have to debug that part of the code. You can test this by replacing the msgbox ("test") End If from that check to: msgbox("folder not found, making") else msgbox ("folder found, skipping") end if.

the problem can be something as stupid as ="" not being correct but = vbNull is.

I removed "If .Range("D8").Value = "Open" Then" and finally got a error on my folder

Ah, good. So you finally can debug your script. I always use if statements with msgbox just to test where my script goes so I know what works and what doesn't. How often I have been staring at the code expecting it to reach a point, only to find out later that it just didn't. Once you understand that, seeing the actual problem is often not that hard anymore. Sometimes I use msgbox to just echo me what the variable is that stage.
